# Dynamically added table in form/div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

[image: 1]

Dynamically create table is appearing outside div tag.

I am creating a responsive Registration form. The input field takes the number of rows required for the table given by user and creates the desired number of rows with fixed number of columns.

I created the table but it is not appearing where I intended it to. Please, give suggestions. Also help with the issue of the labels in the first row i.e. headings (th)s.

```
function createFamTable() {
        var rows = document.getElementById("family-rows").value;
        var tbl = document.createElement("table");
        tbl.id = "family-table1";
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

        for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          var row = document.createElement("tr");
          for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            switch(j) {
                case j=0:
                    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
                    cellText.placeholder = "Enter Name";
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    break;
                case j=1:
                    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
                    cellText.placeholder = "Enter Relation";
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    break;
                case j=2:
                    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
                    cellText.placeholder = "Enter Profession";
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    break;
                case j=3:
                    var cellText = document.createElement('input');
                    cellText.placeholder = "Enter Age";
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    break;
                case j=4:
                    var cellText = document.createElement('select');
                    var arr = ["Select Yes / No","Yes","No"];
                    for (var k=0;k<=2;k++){
                        var opt = document.createElement('option');
                        opt.value = arr[k];
                        opt.text = arr[k];
                        cellText.appendChild(opt);
                    }
                    cell.appendChild(cellText);
                    break;
            }
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }
          tblBody.appendChild(row);
        }
        tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
        document.body.appendChild(tbl);
        cell.setAttribute("border", "2");
        addFirstRow();
}
```

```
<div class="form third">
                    <div class="details education">
                        <span class="title">Family Details</span>
                        <div class="fields">
                            <label>Number of Family Members<span style="color:red;font-size: smaller;">*</span></label>
                            <input type="number" id="family-rows" placeholder="Example: 5" required>
                        </div>
                        <button class="createFamilyTable" onclick="createFamTable()">Add Details</button>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <div class="backBtn1">
                                <i class="uil uil-navigator"></i>
                                <span class="btnText">Back</span>
                            </div>
                            <button class="nextBtn2">
                                <span class="btnText">Next</span>
                                <i class="uil uil-navigator"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I am expecting the table to appear in the div tag (in that white space).

Also I tried adding label headings for the table. Please, help in this issue also.

Comment: You are appending the table element to your body, not your parent containing div.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing good; just some miner mistakes. Add an attribute (type="button") to the Add Details button; by default, the button type in the form is submit, add attribute like this:

```
<button type="button" class="createFamilyTable" onclick="createFamTable()"> Add Details</button>
```

and add a div anywhere

```
<div id="form-table"></div>
```

and this

```
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

replace with

```
document.getElementById('form-table').appendChild(tbl);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('form-table').innerHTML = tbl;
```

Comment: If you can't understand, ask me to comment here and I will fix it.